# how to view all process details from ps –ef command

Tags: linux, process, perl, ps

hi all

I am using the ack.pl in my bash script to search IP's in the Linux OS

only for example , and only to show the problem I will give here short example

```
   #  ( ./ack.pl -Q -a -l --max-count=1 --ignore-dir=log --ignore-dir=logs --ignore-dir=lib  1.1.1.1 /etc/sysconfig ) &
  [2] 25014
```

in this example I run the ack.pl to find the IP 1.1.1.1 under /etc/sysconfig

but when I want to see the process details as the following

```
     # ps -ef | grep  25014

       root 25014 13283   1 14:46:53 pts/1       0:06 perl ./ack.pl -Q -a -l --max-count=1 --ignore-dir=log --ignore-dir=logs --ignor
```

then I not seen the "/etc/sysconfig" in the proccess?

my quastion is:

what I need to do in order to see the PATH - /etc/syscconfig in the process that opened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your console window is trucating the output. Try `ps -ef ww`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159860/viewing-full-output-of-ps-command)